# Is there any way of applying svg filter with specific shape?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

Im experimenting svg filter to get nice animations and effects. It'a new world that i had just discovered, but im facing a problem.
Im trying to reproduce this kind of effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcSU4xH6_Ro
I dont know how to reproduce the circle with the distortion.

I know i could play with filter and svg but actually if i m applying my svg filter to the box all the div have been affect, instead of this circle.

I wonder if it's possible to make svg act like a "lens"
I made a jsFiddle if you want to see the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wekhz7rb/

I would like to do this with CSS only

```
    <div class="box">
    <svg class="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="effect"     
     width="275px" height="275px">
    <filter id="noise">
    <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.05" numOctaves="2" result="noise">    
    </feTurbulence>
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"></feComposite>
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="noise" scale="50">        
    </feDisplacementMap>
    </filter>
    <!-- <circle cx="137" cy="137" r="137" fill="red" filter="url(#noise)">            
    </circle> -->
    </svg>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    <div class="text">DREAMS</div>
    </div>
    @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black);
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #7427FF;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .box {
      height: 550px;
      width: 550px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      filter: url(#noise); 
   // mask: url(#effect);
    }
    .svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 10;
    }

.text {
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 116px;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(117,62,255,1) 0%, 
   rgba(249,37,166,1) 40%, rgba(246,154,180,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation-name: translate;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;

@for $i from 1 through 16 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      animation-delay:  #{$i * 1}s
    }
  }
}

@keyframes translate {
  from {
     transform: translateY(-90px) translateZ(0)
  }
  to {
      transform: translateY(555px) translateZ(0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  Read up on how `feDisplacementMap` works.

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#filters-feDisplacementMapElement

All you have to do is make sure the pixels outside the circle cause a displacement of 0.  For that the colour channel value has to be 0.5 (128).

So if you X channel is the red channel and the Y channel is the green channel, then making the area outside the circle 50% yellow (ie. #808000), should result in a zero displacement.

#### Update: How feDisplacementMap works

How `feDisplacement` works is that it takes a pixel value from the "displacement map" (`in2`) and uses the colour channels of that pixel determine a location elsewhere in the `in` image top copy a pixel from.

So, for example, say we were currently looking at pixel (100,200).

- Look at the pixel at (100,200) in `in2`
- Determine the displacement offset. Lets say it is (-0.4, 0.5).  We'll see how we get these values later.
- Multiply the offset by the `scale`. If scale is `10`, the new offset would be (-4, 5)
- Get the pixel at (`100 - 4`, `200 - 5`) in `in`
- Write out that pixel value to (100,200) in the output (`result`).

**Working out the offset**

Start by looking at the appropriate colour channel (R, G, B, or A) in the `in2` pixel.  The colour channel that is used for the X and Y offsets is set by using the `xChannelSelector` and `yChannelSelector` attributes.

Each of those channels can have a value from 0 to 255. For the R channel 0 means no red, and 255 means full red.  For the purpose of out offset calculations, the 0..255 range is converted to a 0..1 range.

```
+----------------------+------+------------+
| Colour channel value | XC() | XC() - 0.5 |
+----------------------+------+------------+
|        0  (00)       |  0   |    -0.5    |
|       26  (1A)       |  0.1 |    -0.4    |
|      128  (80)       |  0.5 |     0      |
|      255  (FF)       |  1   |     0.5    |
+----------------------+------+------------+
```

So if `xChannelSelector="R"` and `yChannelSelector="G"`, then a pixel value of `#1AFF00` in our `in2` would result in the displacement offset of (-0.4, 0.5) that we used above.

**Back to displacement maps of a particular shape**

From the above, hopefully you can see that if an `in2` pixel channel has a value of `128`, that would result in a zero offset.  Meaning that the output pixel in `result` would be copied directly across from the same position in the input (`in`).

So to create a map with a circular boundary.  All you have to do is make all the pixels outside the circle `128`.

**The problem with `feDisplacementMap`**

Changes in the last couple of years to prevent some security issues related to `feDisplacementMap`, have meant that it can be quite hard to use right now.
There are still left over bugs from that process. For example: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798001

Plus there are bugs with `feImage`: eg. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455986

You'll likely need to use external images with `feImage`, and make sure your CORS settings are correct on your web server.

Alternatively using data URLs with `feImage` seems to work okay.  See [this CodePen from @enxaneta](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/post/svg-waves-with-fedisplacementmap).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So i read the w3's document, but he didn't help me so much. i'm wondering if you have visual example ? he could help a lot, much better than just text (i'm more in visualization ). I'm quite lost right now, i didn't understand everything